# Проблема при переносе сайта на хостинг Kohana 3.2

Tags: сессия, cookie, kohana, php

В базовом классе я пишу

```
Session::$default = 'cookie';
$this->session = Session::instance();
```

т.е. хранить сессию я буду в cookie. В конфиге прописано следующее для cookie

```
'cookie' => array(
        'name' => 'session',
        'encrypted' => TRUE,
        'lifetime' => 43200,
    ),
```

т.е. должна стартовать сессия с именем session, которая будет храниться cookie
На локалхосте она стартует, создается новый cookie, на хостинге - нет.

Скрины:

[Локалхост](http://forum.kohanaframework.su/download/file.php?id=22)

[Хостинг](http://forum.kohanaframework.su/download/file.php?id=23)

Как исправить эту беду?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в сессиях, почему то в куках на хостинге не хотят храниться они. Поменял на native

Answer (score 0):

Я так использую

```
APP/bootstrap.php
Cookie::$path = '/';
Cookie::$domain = '.domain.com';
$session = Session::instance();

APP/config/session.php
return array(
    'native' => array(
        'name' => 'PHPSESSID',
        'lifetime' => 8*60*60,
        'domain' => '.domain.com'
    ),
);
```